# Split list and convert to dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

Given a list as follows:

```
['start year: 2019', 'end year: 2021']
```

How could I split them by `:` and convert into a dataframe?

```
start year      end year
  2019            2021
```

Thanks for your help at advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(':')for x in l ]).set_index(0).T
0 start year end year
1       2019     2021
```

Comment: May I ask: why the column name row's is `0`, index `0` should start with `2019 2021` row, right?